# How to dynamically assign DOM event and then execute it?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

i am trying to execute DOM events within a function that expects the event to handle, such as onmouseover, onclick and so on, by name as a function parameter like so:

```
...

doSomething(target, 'onmouseover');

doSomething : function(tgt, evt)
{
   ...
   o.evt = function() {
      alert(evt);
   }
   ...
}

...
```

The assignment does not throw any errors, so i guess, it is syntactically correct, but it does also not do the alert. Why?

(Please do not recommend using frameworks. I would like to understand my mistake and how to get this managed.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the event dynamically using the `[]` notation:

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9CBWb/)**

```
var obj = {
   doSomething : function(tgt, evt)
   {
      tgt[evt] = function() {
         alert(evt);
      }
   }
};

obj.doSomething(document.getElementById("test"), 'onmouseover');
​
```

Comment: note that OP's code is _not_ within an object literal. +1 for catching `obj.evt` where `obj[evt]` was likely intended.

Comment: @JanDvorak thanks for the +1, you're right about the object literal, I suspected that OP does have one but just snipped the declaration out of the question.